# How to change dropdown title on selected option with reactstrap on react

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I am referring to this dropdown documentation https://reactstrap.github.io/?path=/docs/components-dropdown--dropdown

But I can't seem to find any example that will change the dropdown title on the options selected.. can anyone show me how this is done? It has to be under a function instead of class component

This is the default code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem,
} from 'reactstrap';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

function Example({ direction, ...args }) {
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setDropdownOpen((prevState) => !prevState);

  return (
    <div className="d-flex p-5">
      <Dropdown isOpen={dropdownOpen} toggle={toggle} direction={direction}>
        <DropdownToggle caret>Dropdown</DropdownToggle>
        <DropdownMenu {...args}>
          <DropdownItem header>Header</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Some Action</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem text>Dropdown Item Text</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem disabled>Action (disabled)</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem divider />
          <DropdownItem>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
          <DropdownItem>Quo Action</DropdownItem>
        </DropdownMenu>
      </Dropdown>
    </div>
  );
}

Example.propTypes = {
  direction: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Example;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a state to store the last selected item:

```js
const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("Dropdown");
```

Then you add an `onClick` to every `<DropdownItem/>` so you can update your `selectedItem` state once an option is selected:

```html
//...
<DropdownItem onClick={() => {setSelectedItem('Foo Action')}}>Foo Action</DropdownItem>
<DropdownItem onClick={() => {setSelectedItem('Bar Action')}}>Bar Action</DropdownItem>
//...
```

Finally you can display `selectedItem` as dropdown title.

```html
<DropdownToggle caret>{selectedItem}</DropdownToggle>
```